# Does a Spring Container running in an Appserver have a separate classloader?

Tags: java, spring, classloader

Does a Spring Container running in an Appserver have a separate classloader?
If it does have a separate class loader, what is its parent class loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Spring doesn't have a separate classloader.
If you are in webapp (war), it has a separate classloader. If this war contained inside the ear, this will be the parent one, otherwise there will be some appserver common classloader and so on. It's really depends on appserver.
E.g. in case of Tomcat 5.5, there are usually 4 class loaders in the hierarchy: war -> shared (common for all wars) -> common -> bootstrap
In Tomcat 6 shared and common were merged into the same one.

Additionally without Spring, the Thread#contextClassLoader is undefined. With Spring, you'll get your webapp classloader at Thread#contextClassLoader. And Spring will use the Thread#contextClassLoader for classloading. This is important, since your code (or some third-party) may change the Thread#contextClassLoader, so things will become less expected.

Answer (score 1):

No. Spring doesn't (by default) create a new classloader.

From memory it uses the [`Thread.getContextClassLoader()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader%28%29) classloader, so in a application server it will get the webapp/ejb Classloader that you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Spring context loader listener is part of your web.xml, I'd say that it uses the application class loader.  That means the app server class loader is its parent, and the bootstrap class loader is its grandparent.

Comment: Hi duffymo, When you say it uses the application class loader, can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: Read this: http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch21-ClassLoaders_and_J2EE.htm